# Center text and button elements within Orbit slider?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am having the hardest time figuring out how to make two text elements and a button centered within the Orbit slider in Foundation. I apologize for such a beginner question, but I am brand new to Foundation and some of the syntax is confusing me.

It is a slider with four images, and I'm trying to superimpose the centered h3, p and button elements over the top. Currently they are pulled to the left.

HTML:

```
<div class="row columns">
    <div class="orbit" id="featured" role="region" aria-label="Favorite Space Pictures" data-orbit>
        <ul class="orbit-container" data-caption="#captionOne">
            <button class="orbit-previous" aria-label="previous"><span class="show-for-sr">Previous Slide</span>&#9664;</button>
            <button class="orbit-next" aria-label="next"><span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span>&#9654;</button>
            <li class="orbit-slide is-active">
                <img src="images/manUChelseaAlt.jpg">
                <h3 class="blogTitle">Manchester United v. Chelsea</h3>
                <p>My In-Depth Discovery On Two Of The Most Popular Teams</p>
                <a href="#" class="alert button">Read More</a>
            </li>
            <li class="orbit-slide">
                <img src="images/bestPlayers.jpg">
                <h3 class="blogTitle">The Best Players in Fútbol</h3>
                <p>I learn what makes these special players so unique.</p>
                <a href="#" class="alert button">Read More</a>
            </li>
            <li class="orbit-slide">
                <img src="images/worldCup.jpg">
                <h3 class="blogTitle">The World Cup</h3>
                <p>I figure out why this is the most-watched event in the world.</p>
                <a href="#" class="alert button">Read More</a>
            </li>
            <li class="orbit-slide">
                <img src="images/manuStadium.jpg">
                <h3 class="blogTitle">The Basics of Fútbol</h3>
                <p>I finally learn about the basics.</p>
                <a href="#" class="alert button">Read More</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#featured h3,
#featured p,
#featured .button {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}

#featured h3 {
  top: 35%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#featured p {
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#featured .button {
  top: 65%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.blogTitle {
  font-family: 'Cormorant SC', serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
#featured h3,
#featured p,
#featured .button {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}
```

To:

```
#featured h3,
#featured p,
#featured .button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I still had to remove the margin-left: 10% of course, but that worked wonderfully.